# Shipping Amount Not showing in seller Mail

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using Marketplace Extension in My website. let us assume customer place seller product then admin Approve that order that time seller will get mail on that mail Shipping Charge not Showing

```
 public function massStatusAction()
{
    $orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids', array());
    $countOrder = 0;

    foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        if($order->getStatus()=='pending'){
            $order->setStatus('processing')->save();
            $countOrder++;

            // for mail to seller start
            $_collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
            $_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$orderId);
            $_collection->addFieldToSelect('mageproownerid')
                        ->distinct(true);
            foreach($_collection as $collection){
                $fetchsale = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
                $fetchsale->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$orderId);   
                $fetchsale->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid',$collection->getMageproownerid());
                $totalprice ='';
                $orderinfo = '';
                    $style='style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc";';
                    $tax="<tr><td ".$style."><h3>Tax</h3></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td></tr><tr>";
                    $options="<tr><td ".$style."><h3>Product Options</h3></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td></tr><tr><td ".$style."><b>Options</b></td><td ".$style."><b>Value</b></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td></tr>";        
                foreach($fetchsale as $res){
             $_collection1 = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
        //$_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$orderId);
        $_collection1->addFieldToFilter('mageproid',$res['mageproid']);  
          foreach($_collection1 as $res1){
            $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');
             $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('mpassignproduct'=>'marketplace_assignproduct'))->where('mpassignproduct.mpassignproduct_id=?', $res1->getMpassignproductId());
            $mpassignproduct =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord); 
            if(count($mpassignproduct)) {
                foreach($mpassignproduct as $assignproduct)
                    { 
                        $sku=$assignproduct['sku'];
                    }
                     }else {
                        $sku=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($res['mageproid'])->getSku();
                    }
                }
                    $orderinfo = $orderinfo."<tr>
                                    <td valign='top' align='left' ".$style." >".$res['mageproname']."</td>
                                    <td valign='top' align='left' ".$style.">".$sku."</td>
                                    <td valign='top' align='left' ".$style." >".$res['magequantity']."</td>
                                    <td valign='top' align='left' ".$style.">".Mage::app()->getStore()->formatPrice($res['mageproprice'])."</td>
                                 </tr>";    

                    foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){

                        if($item->getProductId()==$res['mageproid']){
                            $taxAmount=Mage::app()->getStore()->formatPrice($item->getTaxAmount());
                            $tax=$tax."<tr><td ".$style."><b>Tax Amount</b></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style.">".$taxAmount."</td></tr>";
                            $temp=$item->getProductOptions();
                            foreach($temp['options'] as $data){
                                $optionflag=1;
                                $options=$options."<tr><td ".$style."><b>".$data['label']."</b></td><td ".$style.">".$data['value']."</td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td></tr>";
                                }
                            }
                    }
                    $totalprice = $totalprice+$res['mageproprice'];
                    $userdata = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($res['mageproownerid']);              
                    $Username = $userdata['firstname'];
                    $useremail = $userdata['email'];            
                }

                $shipcharge = $order->getShippingAmount();
                if($item->getTaxAmount()>0){
                    $orderinfo=$orderinfo.$tax;
                }
                if($optionflag==1){
                    $orderinfo=$orderinfo.$options;
                }
                $orderinfo = $orderinfo."</tbody><tbody><tr>
                                            <td align='right' style='padding:3px 9px' colspan='3'>Grandtotal</td>
                                            <td align='right' style='padding:3px 9px' colspan='3'><span>".Mage::app()->getStore()->formatPrice($totalprice+$item->getTaxAmount())."</span></td>
                                        </tr>";

                $billingId = $order->getBillingAddress()->getId();
                $billaddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($billingId);
                $billinginfo = $billaddress['firstname'].'<br/>'.$billaddress['street'].'<br/>'.$billaddress['city'].' '.$billaddress['region'].' '.$billaddress['postcode'].'<br/>'.Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($billaddress['country_id'])->getName().'<br/>T:'.$billaddress['telephone'];  

                if($order->getShippingAddress()!='')
                    $shippingId = $order->getShippingAddress()->getId();
                else
                    $shippingId = $billingId;
                $address = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($shippingId);                
                $shippinginfo = $address['firstname'].'<br/>'.$address['street'].'<br/>'.$address['city'].' '.$address['region'].' '.$address['postcode'].'<br/>'.Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($address['country_id'])->getName().'<br/>T:'.$address['telephone']; 

                $payment = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();
                if($order->getShippingAddress()){
                    $shippingId = $order->getShippingAddress()->getId();
                    $address = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($shippingId);                
                    $shippinginfo = $address['firstname'].'<br/>'.$address['street'].'<br/>'.$address['city'].' '.$address['region'].' '.$address['postcode'].'<br/>'.Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($address['country_id'])->getName().'<br/>T:'.$address['telephone']; 
                    $shipping = $order->getShippingDescription();   
                    $shippinfo = $shippinginfo;
                    $shippingd = $shipping;     
                }
                $emailTemp = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('webkulorderinvoice');

                $emailTempVariables = array();              
                $adminEmail=Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
                $adminUsername = 'Admin';
                if(isset($res['seller_order_id']) && $res['seller_order_id']!==NULL && $res['seller_order_id']!=="")
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar1'] = $res['seller_order_id'];
                else
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar1'] = $res['magerealorderid'];
                $emailTempVariables['myvar2'] = $res['cleared_at'];
                $emailTempVariables['myvar4'] = $billinginfo;
                $emailTempVariables['myvar5'] = $payment;
                $emailTempVariables['myvar6'] = $shippinfo;
                $emailTempVariables['myvar9'] = $shippingd;
                $emailTempVariables['myvar8'] = $orderinfo;
                $emailTempVariables['myvar3'] =$Username;

                $processedTemplate = $emailTemp->getProcessedTemplate($emailTempVariables);

                $emailTemp->setSenderName($adminUsername);
                $emailTemp->setSenderEmail($adminEmail);
                $emailTemp->send($useremail,$Username,$emailTempVariables);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are getting shipping amount `$shipcharge = $order->getShippingAmount();` but not using that variable to display in the email.

Comment: Do you mean one order have two shipping amount(different shipping amount) for different seller? Describe how it works.

Comment: @John Let assume one order have 2 product with 2 different seller. Seller A - 50 rs Shipping Charge Seller -B 30rs Shipping Charge if admin approve that order both seller will get a mail exact shipping price

Comment: where you define shipping amount for particular seller?

Comment: After admin approve that order each seller got mail that mail i need to mention shipping charge

Comment: I mean to say in which model you set shipping price for seller?

Comment: sorry i didn't get

Comment: Which Magento version do you use? Did you applied all patchs? After patch 6788 you need allow custom variables for emails transacional. You can edit white list in `System > Permissions > Variables`

Answer (score 0):

edit your code

```
public function massStatusAction()
{
    $orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids', array());
    $countOrder = 0;

    foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        if($order->getStatus()=='pending'){
            $order->setStatus('processing')->save();
            $countOrder++;

            // for mail to seller start
            $_collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
            $_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$orderId);
            $_collection->addFieldToSelect('mageproownerid')
                        ->distinct(true);
            foreach($_collection as $collection){
                $fetchsale = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
                $fetchsale->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$orderId);   
                $fetchsale->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid',$collection->getMageproownerid());
                $totalprice ='';
                $orderinfo = '';
                    $style='style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc";';
                    $tax="<tr><td ".$style."><h3>Tax</h3></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td></tr><tr>";
                    $options="<tr><td ".$style."><h3>Product Options</h3></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td></tr><tr><td ".$style."><b>Options</b></td><td ".$style."><b>Value</b></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td></tr>";        
                foreach($fetchsale as $res){
             $_collection1 = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
        //$_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$orderId);
        $_collection1->addFieldToFilter('mageproid',$res['mageproid']);  
          foreach($_collection1 as $res1){
            $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');
             $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('mpassignproduct'=>'marketplace_assignproduct'))->where('mpassignproduct.mpassignproduct_id=?', $res1->getMpassignproductId());
            $mpassignproduct =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord); 
            if(count($mpassignproduct)) {
                foreach($mpassignproduct as $assignproduct)
                    { 
                        $sku=$assignproduct['sku'];
                    }
                     }else {
                        $sku=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($res['mageproid'])->getSku();
                    }
                }
                    $orderinfo = $orderinfo."<tr>
                                    <td valign='top' align='left' ".$style." >".$res['mageproname']."</td>
                                    <td valign='top' align='left' ".$style.">".$sku."</td>
                                    <td valign='top' align='left' ".$style." >".$res['magequantity']."</td>
                                    <td valign='top' align='left' ".$style.">".Mage::app()->getStore()->formatPrice($res['mageproprice'])."</td>
                                 </tr>";    

                    foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){

                        if($item->getProductId()==$res['mageproid']){
                            $taxAmount=Mage::app()->getStore()->formatPrice($item->getTaxAmount());
                            $tax=$tax."<tr><td ".$style."><b>Tax Amount</b></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style.">".$taxAmount."</td></tr>";
                            $temp=$item->getProductOptions();
                            foreach($temp['options'] as $data){
                                $optionflag=1;
                                $options=$options."<tr><td ".$style."><b>".$data['label']."</b></td><td ".$style.">".$data['value']."</td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td></tr>";
                                }
                            }
                    }
                    $totalprice = $totalprice+$res['mageproprice'];
                    $userdata = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($res['mageproownerid']);              
                    $Username = $userdata['firstname'];
                    $useremail = $userdata['email'];

                    $shipcharge = $order->getShippingAmount();
                if($item->getTaxAmount()>0){
                    $orderinfo=$orderinfo.$tax;
                }
                if($optionflag==1){
                    $orderinfo=$orderinfo.$options;
                }
                $orderinfo = $orderinfo."</tbody><tbody><tr>
                                            <td align='right' style='padding:3px 9px' colspan='3'>Grandtotal</td>
                                            <td align='right' style='padding:3px 9px' colspan='3'><span>".Mage::app()->getStore()->formatPrice($totalprice+$item->getTaxAmount())."</span></td>
                                        </tr>";

                $billingId = $order->getBillingAddress()->getId();
                $billaddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($billingId);
                $billinginfo = $billaddress['firstname'].'<br/>'.$billaddress['street'].'<br/>'.$billaddress['city'].' '.$billaddress['region'].' '.$billaddress['postcode'].'<br/>'.Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($billaddress['country_id'])->getName().'<br/>T:'.$billaddress['telephone'];  

                if($order->getShippingAddress()!='')
                    $shippingId = $order->getShippingAddress()->getId();
                else
                    $shippingId = $billingId;
                $address = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($shippingId);                
                $shippinginfo = $address['firstname'].'<br/>'.$address['street'].'<br/>'.$address['city'].' '.$address['region'].' '.$address['postcode'].'<br/>'.Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($address['country_id'])->getName().'<br/>T:'.$address['telephone']; 

                $payment = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();
                if($order->getShippingAddress()){
                    $shippingId = $order->getShippingAddress()->getId();
                    $address = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($shippingId);                
                    $shippinginfo = $address['firstname'].'<br/>'.$address['street'].'<br/>'.$address['city'].' '.$address['region'].' '.$address['postcode'].'<br/>'.Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($address['country_id'])->getName().'<br/>T:'.$address['telephone']; 
                    $shipping = $order->getShippingDescription();   
                    $shippinfo = $shippinginfo;
                    $shippingd = $shipping;     
                }
                $emailTemp = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('webkulorderinvoice');

                $emailTempVariables = array();              
                $adminEmail=Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
                $adminUsername = 'Admin';
                if(isset($res['seller_order_id']) && $res['seller_order_id']!==NULL && $res['seller_order_id']!=="")
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar1'] = $res['seller_order_id'];
                else
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar1'] = $res['magerealorderid'];
                $emailTempVariables['myvar2'] = $res['cleared_at'];
                $emailTempVariables['myvar4'] = $billinginfo;
                $emailTempVariables['myvar5'] = $payment;
                $emailTempVariables['myvar6'] = $shippinfo;
                $emailTempVariables['myvar9'] = $shippingd;
                $emailTempVariables['myvar8'] = $orderinfo;
                $emailTempVariables['myvar3'] =$Username;
                //shipping charge added to email template variable
                $emailTempVariables['myvarShipAmount'] = $shipcharge;

                $processedTemplate = $emailTemp->getProcessedTemplate($emailTempVariables);

                $emailTemp->setSenderName($adminUsername);
                $emailTemp->setSenderEmail($adminEmail);
                $emailTemp->send($useremail,$Username,$emailTempVariables);


                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your email template "webkulorderinvoice" add below code

```
Shipping Amount: {{var myvarShipAmoun}}
```

Comment: I tried Previously. Let us assume 2 seller product in order if i approve order both seller have same shipping price then it work other wise it shows one seller shipping price both seller mail

Comment: Updated code please try with this and make sure if one order have two seller product then both have same shipping price

Comment: No i can't restrict each seller have different shipping price

Comment: It is working or not for you and explain briefly your exact problem

Comment: I already tried for same price in both seller but different price it not work this is my problem

Comment: You need to debug code for shipping amount for particular seller. In code no specification about seller shipping amount so i can't able to help you.

Comment: you are sending mail from wrong place because $shipping amount always override for both orders

Comment: which marketplace extension you are using?

Comment: I think you are not sending shipping amount so its blank can you show template or other file with using this variable  $emailTempVariables['myvar9'] = $shippingd;

Comment: Shipping amount already on email as per now this variable for shipping description

Comment: @ShakirKhan i am using Webkul marktplace

Comment: then try to contact webkul support i think if there are any problem in their extension they will help .

Comment: Okay thank i will check with them

Comment: If it helps you then mark as accepted